# As a non-developer, how do I download logs so I can help diagnose why an app is crashing?

Tags: logging

I am not an Android developer, but one of the apps I use is now saying "Unfortunately ... has stopped."

I would like to look at the system logs to help figure out why, but all I can find is references to [`logcat`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) and it would be a lot more convenient if I didn't have to download Android Studio just to do this one thing.

Is there a way to get the logs without using Android Studio?

Comment: Read the [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) of the tag you used for more

Comment: No need to use Android Studio, just need ADB command-line tool.